# Every subgroup of a finitely generated abelian group $G$ is a direct sum of factors each of which is a subgroup of the corresponding factors of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a finitely generated abelian group so that $G= \mathbb Z_{r_1} \oplus ... \oplus \mathbb Z_{r_s} \oplus (\mathbb Z \oplus ... \oplus \mathbb Z)$. If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, does it follow that $H= \mathbb Z_{v_1} \oplus ... \oplus \mathbb Z_{v_s} \oplus (\mathbb Z \oplus... \oplus Z)$ where each $\mathbb Z_{v_j}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_{r_j}$ and the number of copies of $\mathbb Z$ in $H$ is less than that in $G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

For instance, the subgroup $\left\{(0,0),(1,1)\right\}\in\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is not a product of subgroups.

If it was, say, $H\times K$, then $1\in H$ and $1\in K$ would imply $H\times K=G$, which is not the case.

The same counterexample  $\left<(1,1)\right>$ holds for infinite cyclic groups as well.

Comment: Thanks. It was a natural counterexample

Comment: You're welcome. In general, intuitively, subgroups of the form $H\times K$ are rare amongst all subgroups.